# Как мне включить ноутбук который выдает поиск неисправностей при запуске?

Tags: windows

Запускаю компьютер, но по итогу открывается всегда такая панель, с чем может быть связано и можно ли зафискить каким то образом без потери данных?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачайте [образ Сергея Стрельца](https://sergeistrelec.ru/) и установите Ventoy на флешку тогда просто перекиньте .iso файл Сергея Стрельца на флешку и загрузитесь из неё. Там можете зайти в Мой Компьютер и сохранить важные файлы.